# Connecting R and Presto using LDAP https authentication

Tags: r, presto

I am trying to connect R with presto using RPresto package. My main aim is when connecting R with Presto user should get authentication window, and once that is done user should be able to fetch the queries.

I have tried basic authentication using http and it was successful, but while connecting via https I am getting error.

Basic Authentication method which worked for me

```
library(dplyr)
library(RPresto)
db <- src_presto(
  host='http://example.com',
  port=XXXX,
  user=Sys.getenv('USER'),
  schema='test',
  catalog='hive'
)
```

## ------------------------------------------------------

## trying to connect presto with R using ssl https

```
library(dplyr)
library(RPresto)
library(httr)
db <- src_presto(
  host='https://example.com',
  port=(secure port),
  user=Sys.getenv('USER'),
  schema='test',
  catalog='hive'
)
```

Results after running Presto R using https

db
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
Peer's Certificate has expired.

Comment: "`Peer's Certificate has expired`" -- do you have valid SSL/TLS certificate?

Comment: It seems the issue with Peers certificate, once admin gets new certificate then I will try to run my script. But what do you think about the script? is it valid or do i need to add any other parameters?

Comment: Admin team renewed certificate still getting same error, can anyone help?